# Cross factor for dependent terms in a differential?

Tags: differentiation, calculus, differential-equations

How do you derive a cross factor to decouple differentials into independent differentials? For example:
$$ d(PV)= PdV+VdP $$
$$ PV=\int{PdV}+\int{VdP} $$

Obviously dP and dV are related. Do you simply write dP in terms of dV? What other methods are there where you can leave the differential as is but with a multiplicative cross factor term?

Comment: This [mse post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4774869/949989) shows under what condition  $dP$ can be written in terms of $dV\,.$ It is a pure math question. Regarding the physics: The pressure $P$ is  a function of volume $V$ only under certain [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law#Definition).

Answer (score 0):

The formula $d(pV)=pdV+Vdp$ is just Leibniz's rule on the differential quotient of the product of two function, $(fg)'=gf'+fg'$, written in the language of infinitesimals (differentials).

For one variable functions, $\frac{d(f(x)g(x))}{dx}=g(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}+f(x)\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$.

For a function of several variables, $x_1, x_2, ..x_n$, along a curve $x_1(t), x_2(t),...x_n(t)$, the total derivative of $f^*(t)=f(x_1(t),x_2(t),..,x_n(t))$ is defined by
$$\frac{df^*(t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\frac{dx_2}{dt}+...+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\frac{dx_n}{dt},$$ and again the identity holds for $\frac{d(f^*(t)g^*(t))}{dt}=g^*(t)\frac{df^*(t)}{dt}+f^*(t)\frac{dg^*(t)}{dt}$.

Now "simplify" your notation and with Leibniz (or Euler) drop $dt$ without losing any sleep over it and write
$${d(f^*(t)g^*(t))}=g^*(t){df^*(t)}+f^*(t){dg^*(t)}$$